# Can anyone tell me what's the /4.0 stand for here in kernel nparray for convolve?

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision

I am writing python with convolve kernel. Here in the example, there is a `/4.0`  sufix in the end of the code and I cannot find any explanation about it in the nparray api. What's it stand for? Thank you!

```
B_kernel = np.array(
        [[2, 1, 2],
         [1, 4, 1],
         [2, 1, 2]]) / 4.0
```

Comment: normalization for the kernel. But first from where are you getting this? please provide more details. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Generally kernels are normalized to that the sum is equal to 1 which is strangely not the case here. Normalizing a kernel prevent colour saturation in picture and enable the conservation of some properties in simulations (eg. energy in physics).